# How to delete a snapshot view from CCRC when "Remove ClearCase view" is disabled?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I'm running a system with Clearcase Remote Client version 7.0.1.CU04.
I don't have cleartool installed on the system, so a command-line solution for my problem is probably unavailable to me.

Inside of CCRC, I've created many views that appear in the ClearCase Navigator pane.
I'd like to delete these to reduce clutter, but see no UI options to do it.
Right-clicking will show me a disabled "`delete`" in the pop-up menu list.  And also the "Remove ClearCase View" under the "Environment" menu is disabled.  Deleting the associated directory in the filesystem (not CCRC) will just leave an orphaned item in the list shown in CCRC.

How can I delete these views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that <del>CCRC doesn't come with any cleartool CLI</del> -- scratch that: with CCRC7.1 onwards, you do have a [CCRC Remote CLI](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929) (including a `rmview` command!).
They can be deleted on the CCRC server where they are listed as ccweb views, [like this technote mentions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21172246).
But it also mentions:
"The proper way to remove a ClearCase Web view is through the CCWeb interface or CCRC interface."

So it must be possible (and has always been, according to the [feature matrix](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21233090)).

- Select a view
- Right-click and select **Remove ClearCase View** (not "delete")

Are your views within a working set?
There is a [bug associated with views in working set](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=986&context=SSSH3S&context=SSSTY3&context=SSCSNZN&context=SSSTWP&context=SSCGQ7B&context=SSCGQ7D&context=SSDV2W&uid=swg1PK85019&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Remove ClearCase View is not shown in the right-click options from views in the "Clearcase Navigator" pane.  It does appear in the top menu under "Environment", but it is disabled here.  Will check for CCRC Remote CLI and report back.

Comment: It will be some time before I can try out the CCRC remote CLI solution.  IT dept has to upgrade the server to match that version first.  Any ideas why the "remove clearcase view" option is disabled?  This otherwise seems like the straightforward way to delete the view.

Comment: @Erik: just saw your answer. What version of CCRC are you using?

Comment: CCRC version is 7.0.1.CU04.  I can't upgrade anytime soon.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to remove the list of views from your CCRC client, you can simply edit this file in your default home directory --> C:\Documents and Settings\.ccase_wvreg

This file contains the list of CCRC views storage directory on your local machine.

However, doing this doesnt cleanup the registry server, you need to ask the CC admin to cleanup the reg server. This 2 commands will work for the admins.

cleartool unregister

cleartool rmtag

Comment: I work in an organization led by a faceless IT department like the OP, so this solution was gold for me!  I could easily remove the views from my list of views in Eclipse/CCRC, and then send off the list of views that were undeletable in an IT request, to be deleted 6 months down the road when some poor overworked IT staffer finally gets to it.

Comment: By the way, under Linux/Unix, this file is in ~/.ccase_wvreg.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem with removing the view being greyed out when I was connected to the view and right clicked on the view.  This problem went away accidentally when I did the following:

1. Exited CCRC client
2. Got back into CCRC client
3. Expanded "My Views"
4. Right click on the view to be removed without connecting to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very unintuitive way to remove the ClearCase View.  Although the "Remove ClearCase View" option under the "Environment" is shown disabled, *it can still be chosen*.  And it will remove the view.  So there is some bug in CCRC apparently.